# docker container lifecycle confusion

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker, and I find the definitions of containers' lifecycle differ a lot.

here is what "Manning.Docker.in.Action.2016.3" shows：
[image]

here is what google gives me:

https://medium.com/@nagarwal/lifecycle-of-docker-container-d2da9f85959

here is what the official document says：

> status：   One of created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited, or dead

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

So what's going on here? I guess some new states(and renaming) are introduced in newer version of Docker?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your linked diagram separates `docker create` from `docker start`, it includes "die" as a state transition, and it shows how to get to the "restarting" state.  That's all valid, though it leads to a more complicated state machine.

(`docker create` wasn't in the very first versions of Docker but [it appeared in Docker 1.3.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-2014-10-14) in 2014, which should predate your diagram.)

Practically I might suggest an even simpler state machine:

```
-------> running -+------> stopped ------>
  run             | stop             rm
                  \------> exited  ------>
           process exits             rm
```

That is, never try to restart a container or make changes inside a running container; if you need to tweak anything, delete the existing container and create a new one.  This gives you a consistent environment (when the main container process starts you always know what's in its filesystem, up to mounted data).  It also matches what happens in cluster environments like Kubernetes, where the cluster manager will routinely create and delete containers for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get in a situation where internet gives you different answers, you should consider trying it yourself. Especially with technologies like docker, where it is pretty simple to make tests. For example:

I want to run a container (I will use nginx):

`docker run -d nginx`

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
258cd2edbed8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        80/tcp              jolly_golick
```

Note: docker will keep a container running only if there is a process running in it.

If you would start a `debian` container (for example), you would see how it immediately stop, as there is nothing running in it. So you could do

`docker run -d debian sleep 10`

and see that the container is up for 10 seconds.

When a container is running, you can do some things on it. You can't do other things, like removing it. To remove a container, you need to stop it first (or kill it), or force container removal.

Note: You would get all this info from docker itself, if you would be playing around with it, as it would return these info. Like if you would try to remove a running container, you would get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 258cd2edbed85bed23ab543312968bd893c1fbd9ba81de40366337f434daedff. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
```

I can't do all possible combinations here. You would get a similar error if you would try removing a paused container. Just play with it, and you will get a clear picture of how it works.